# How to take high resolution pictures?

Tags: canon-550d, resolution

I came across this site [unsplash](http://unsplash.com) and they post free high resolution pictures to use. I have a canon550D with the standard kit 18-55m and a 50mm lens. How are these high resolution pictures achieved? I use lightroom for some basic editing... any information or advice would be great.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. The resolution of the photos on unsplash appear to be between about 10 and 30 megapixels. As your camera is 18 megapixels you should be able to produce images of similar resolution (10-18 megapixels).

Comment: @DanWolfgang they look so much more crisp to my eye, than anything I have taken...

Answer (score 0):

> some basic editing...

That's what makes the difference.
They probably use not so basic editing like sharpening, local adjustments, etc 
and they probably also do not just apply some of it, but a lot.

To cut a long story short: These are not images that come straight out of the camera and your will not achieve such results with the camera and basic editing alone.